# Partial derivative equality

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

I'm working through Colley's Vector Calculus 3rd edition to reacclimate and introduce myself to all things vectors and differential forms.  The following question is stumping me.
Suppose $z=f(x,y)$ has continuous partial derivatives.  Let $x=e^r\cos \theta$ and $y=e^r\sin\theta$.  Show that
$$\left(\frac{\partial{z}}{\partial{x}}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\partial{z}}{\partial{y}}\right)^2=e^{-2r}\left[\left(\frac{\partial{z}}{\partial{r}}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\partial{z}}{\partial{\theta}}\right)^2\right]$$
So I almost have the answer but I keep getting a pesky $\cos^2\theta$.
$$e^{-2r}\left[\left(\frac{\partial{z}}{\partial{r}}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\partial{z}}{\partial{\theta}}\right)^2\right]=e^{-2r}\left[\left(\frac{\partial{z}}{\partial{x}}\cdot{\frac{\partial{x}}{\partial{r}}}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\partial{z}}{\partial{y}}\cdot{\frac{\partial{y}}{\partial{\theta}}}\right)^2\right]=e^{-2r}\left[\left(\frac{\partial{z}}{\partial{x}}\cdot{e^r\cos\theta}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\partial{z}}{\partial{y}}\cdot{e^r\cos\theta}\right)^2\right]=\cos^2\theta\left[\left(\frac{\partial{z}}{\partial{x}}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\partial{z}}{\partial{y}}\right)\right]^2$$
Where is my error?

Comment: $\displaystyle{\partial z\over \partial r} = {\partial z\over \partial x}{\partial x\over \partial r}+\color{maroon}{{\partial z\over \partial y}{\partial y\over \partial r}}$. You forgot the $\color{maroon}{\text{second}}$ term. Similarly, for $\displaystyle{\partial z\over\partial\theta}$...

Comment: Oh my god that was dumb.  I should have known that the $sin^2\theta$ would appear there and then cancel.  Too many $\partial$'s!  Thanks!

Comment: I changed \text{cos } to \cos.  That is standard usage, and automatically gives you proper spacing in things like $a\cos b$.

Comment: Awesome.  Thanks @michaelhardy!